# Notepad++ Find/Replace

Tags: notepad++

I am looking for a way to do a find/replace within a doc that will replace a variable with fields from another doc.

So on doc one there are multiple instances of the following:

```
int <x/y>
int <x/y>
int <x/y>
```

On the sec doc I would have

```
3/1
3/2
3/2
```

I want to do a find on  and replace with the data on the other doc starting at 3/1

So in the end my 1st doc would look like this

```
int 3/1
int 3/2
int 3/3
```

Is there a way to set this up?  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could record a macro and play it back

Comment: would column copy/paste help? Alt+Mouse (or Alt+Shift+Arrow) to select, then Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to create a script for this on a permanent basis, I don't think there is a way around doing a little bit of programming.

Something like this can be done as Sathya suggested, recording a macro, I wouldn't suggest this. Or possibly research simple batch scripting in windows (possibly a better solution). I myself think that using batch for loops with tokens is much more complicated than real programming languages.

I myself would prefer to do this in a real programming language, things like this are really easy in python, or any of the c languages.

Use [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) as a resource for help if you decide to go this route.

**Update**

Another suggestion I thought of is possibly using excel. I don't know what format you are forced to use, but if you can switch to a delimiter over what your format is now, you can quickly do all of this in excel. Otherwise, you have to dive into programming.

Comment: Mine was more like a half suggestion :) I really doubt this is possible without fair bit of scripting / programmiing

Comment: @Sathya agreed, I do not think it is.